# Error reading file: Type of 'await' operand must either be a valid promise or must not contain a callable 'then' member

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have the error: 'Type of 'await' operand must either be a valid promise or must not contain a callable 'then' member.' when changing the format of a test from using promise .then() based syntax which worked to use async/await. Which was my attempt below.

```js
 it('downloads successfully', async () => {
        cy.get(downloadButton).click();

        const csv = await cy.readFile(filename, { timeout: 15000 });
        csv.should('have.length.gt', 20);
        expect(csv, 'number of records').to.have.length(10);
})
```

before

```js
cy.readFile(filename, { timeout: 15000 })
          .should('have.length.gt', 20)
          .then(validateCsv);
```

Comment: Is this Cypress? Cypress' IO methods don't return `Promise<T>`. See here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Subject-Management

Comment: Thanks it turns out that this is the answer. I didn't realise that cypress's promises aren't really promises. Happy to accept if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`readFile` method doesn't return a promise and hence you can't use await on it but `should` does. You can write your above implementation like

```
 it('downloads successfully', async () => {
        cy.get(downloadButton).click();

        const csv = cy.readFile(filename, { timeout: 15000 });
        const res= await csv.should('have.length.gt', 20);
        expect(res, 'number of records').to.have.length(10);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Bizarrely I still get the same error on the `const res = await csv.should(...)`line.